# Is there any way to highlight text in textbox?

Tags: jquery, vb.net, highlight

I am beginner to vb.net, currently I'm doing a web project which needs to compare 2 text file and highlight the differences. I have been using [jQuery highlightTextarea](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/#installation) trying to highlight the differences, but I'm still unable to do it. Is there any other way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('TextBox2').highlightTextarea({
        words: ['(', ')']
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have also used the same js, it's a good for text highlight.What is the error.

Comment: your selector is not right, if TextBox2 is a class use `$('.TextBox2')`. if it is a ID use `$('#TextBox2')`

Comment: Use $('textarea').highlightTextarea({});

Comment: @Prasanna it give me an error Line: 1 Error: 'module' is undefined

Comment: did you read this part under installation: "The `module` is available on Bower. Add `jquery-highlighttextarea` to your `bower.json` file install or install it manually with `bower install jquery-highlighttextarea`."

Answer (score 0):

The vb.net method is to set the text box selection with .Select and refer to or change the selection with .SelectedText. Note that this is a functional selection and will only work for one continuous portion of the text. If you are looking for a cosmetic highlighting feature this will not work. Based on the above, I believe what you want should be:

```
Dim sStart As Integer, sEnd As Integer
sStart = InStr(TextBox2.Text, "(")
sEnd = InStr(TextBox2.Text, ")")
TextBox2.Select(sStart, sEnd - sStart + 1)
```